# code php on line when import on ftp

Tags: php, ftp

When i import my php files to ftp all the code of each file stands on 1 line. Then when there is a commentary it puts in commentary all the code that comes after. How to do to import file and keep  the form ?

Comment: It sounds like you're file encodings are getting confused, and the system your FTPing to isn't recognising your line breaks. What OSes are you using?

Comment: Guillaume : use @andrewsi to send a signal to him. Otherwise he won't see you answered

Comment: @andrewsi are you still here ?

Comment: Just use a different editor, it doesn't understand unix line endings, so editors like notepad will put everything on one line. What editor are you using?

Comment: notepadd++, but sometime it works so i don't really understand what's happening.

Comment: When i open those files with netbeans nothing changes, all the form is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, i just had to change the uploading format. Put binary instead of automatic.